# Why does xcode not have an option to create tests anymore?

Tags: xcode

As of today, I can no longer create projects with unit tests in Xcode. Normally it looks like this:

[image: correct layout]

As of today it looks like this:
[image: incorrect layout]

How to I get back the option to create unit tests? I can kind of manually create unit tests, but they don't work with CMD-U, can't find objects unless they're explicitly imported, and cause either linker errors or EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when run.

Comment: Cant you just add a test target? Are you creating an iOS project?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can create a project with unit tests for any kind of project type EXCEPT "Command Line Tool".

So if you want to have unit tests with your command line tool, best to create it as a framework project with unit tests, then add source files to both the framework (for the unit tests) and to your command line tool. Awkward and clunky, but it works.